# Using 'this' from a prototype function called from async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, this

I'm trying to access a variable by using 'this' but the context changes because my function is called by `async.series`. Here is a sample of my code :)

```
var search = function(url) {
    this.music = url;
}

search.prototype.test = function() {
    async.series({
        songId: this.getSongId
    }, function(err, results) {});
};

search.prototype.getSongId = function(callback) {
    console.log(this.music) // Prints 'undefined'
}
module.exports = search;
```

When I'm doing

```
var engine = require('./lib/index.js');
var search = new engine('test');
search.test();
```

I get 'undefined'.
Is there a way to bind 'this' to the async.series function or should I just pass my value as an argument?

Comment: Yes, and your terminology was perfect: [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: You are redefining `test` in the prototype. Why?

Comment: Yea reading that code over a couple times, I can't tell what's going on.

Comment: @thefourtheye I made a mistake when building my example. It is fixed now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pointy pointed out, .bind() was actually the right way to go.
After some research here is how I solved my problem.

```
search.prototype.test = function() {
    async.series({
        songId: this.getSongId.bind(this) //binding "this" here!
    }, function(err, results) {});
};
```

Thanks :)